# Call base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest in overrided OnAuthorization Method of AuthorizeAttribute cause to hit twice on OnAuthorization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I override OnAuthorization method in AuthorizeAttribute class for custom implementation. when user has authorized i call  base.OnAuthorization(filterContext); and if not authorized i call base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);. this cause to hit one more time on OnAuthorization when user is not authorized.

Comment: Hi Chaminda Jayanath Udawatte What is your question ? Do you want "OnAuthorization" to be hit only one time ???

Comment: Hi,  Yes, Actually, when i debug,for a one call it hit two times

Comment: Hi Chaminda, did you get the answer? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Any update? Getting the game issue when I return `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` inside `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` it calls `OnAuthorization` again which then calls `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` again